# How to retrieve all fields from a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to retrieve just the field names and not their values.

My current code is:

```
    app.get("/api/borough_all_fields", function(req, res){
    // set the type of content in the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var borFld = null;

    // what to put in here?

    // add the results to an array
    respJson["results"] = [ borFld ];
    res.end( JSON.stringify( respJson ) );
});
```

Also how to specify a field name and return its value for all the records? Example, specify `GSS_code` and have all the values returned, only for the gss code along with their names?

Comment: you can't get key's name only as there is a key-value pair stored in the json.

Comment: @Atula The task clearly says:

"Returns: all the field names that exist in the datasets (e.g., “General_Fertility_Rate-2013”, etc.). **Do not return the field values of theboroughs, just the field names.**

So there must be some way

Comment: well if you know, post it here. It would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the correct json path.

```
var borFld = Object.keys(json.features[0].properties);
```

If you have multiple objects in the array then you need to run a for loop on array and pass the above line it will return the required result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a builtin  object Function
If you have object like this

```
var jsonObj = {"person":"me","age":"30"};
var borFld = Object.keys(jsonObj);  // returns ["person", "age"]
```

Comment: The result of that is in track, but not what I want. It returns me the following: "{"results":[["type","crs","features"]]}".

I need it to return GSS_code, Name, Population, Area...

Comment: Can you share your JSON and expected result ?

Comment: The expected result is kinda like the one above, as for the json I'm not sure how to upload the file but the beginning is like this: {"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"NAME":"Kingston upon Thames","GSS_CODE":"E09000021","HECTARES":3726.117,"NONLD_AREA":0,"ONS_INNER":"F","SUB_2009":null,"SUB_2006":null,"Area_name":"Kingston upon Thames","Inner_Outer_London":"Outer London","GLA_Population_Estimate_2015":170900,"GLA_Household_Estimate_2015":66870......

Comment: You need to pass the right part of your JSON into `Object.keys`, something like `Object.keys(json.features[0].properties)`.

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier perfect! it worked like a charm!! "results":[["NAME","GSS_CODE","HECTARES","NONLD_AREA","ONS_INNER","SUB_2009","SUB_2006","Area_name","Inner_Outer_London","GLA_Population_Estimate_2015","GLA_Household_Estimate_2015","Inland_Area_Hectares","Population_density_per_hectare_2015","Average_Age_2015","Proportion_of_population_aged_0-15_2015","Proportion_of_population_of_working-age_2015","Proportion_of_population_aged_65_and_over_2015","Net_internal_migration_2014","Net_international_migration_2014","Net_natural_change_2014","PC_of_resident_population_bo